# Trouble with cron job scheduling based on activity

Tags: javascript, cron, electron, node-cron

I've got a `cron.schedule` function here that runs the code once every second. When the user is on the website, it displays **"In website"** and when they enter a game, it shows **"In game"** However, when the user is in the game, it stops the `cron.schedule`, so the code doesn't run every second when the user returns to the website. Any help will be appreciated.

The `checkGameStatus()` function **returns** either `true` or `false`. true being in the user is in the website, false being the user being in game.

```
let task = cron.schedule("* * * * * *", async () => {
    let isWebsite = await checkGameStatus();
    if (isWebsite) {
        task.start();
        console.log("In website")
    } else {
        task.stop();
        //ipcRenderer.send("trackgame", game, placeid)
        console.log("In game")
    }
});
```

Any help will be appreicated! 
Note: This is a electron project

Comment: Maybe checkGameStatus misbehaves when the game is running.  If you await a promise that never resolves/rejects, you'd never log anything, or start/stop anything, making it seem as if cron wasnt running.  adding a console.log before the await might help figure things out.

Comment: is this supposed to be part of client side code ?

Comment: @RudyMartin It is the renderer side. As I am using this in electron. Sorry If I didn't specify.

Comment: It makes no sense to call `task.start()` inside the task. If the code executes, the task is already started. And when the task is stopped, it won't call the function again to perform the `isWebsite` check.

Comment: Why do you do this with `cron`? Why not just have the code that's updates the game status display the status messages?

Comment: @Barmar When the user is in-game it will create a window, I am using `cron.stop()` to stop the cron job to prevent lots of windows getting created.

Comment: Can't you detect the transition from not-in-game to in-game?

Comment: @Barmar 
I don't think so. I'm using noblox.js to check if a player is online. It fetches the data about whether the player is currently in the game or on the website. So, I don't think I can detect when the player switches. I have only thought about just constantly fetching the data until it changes to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't stop the task. Use a global variable to keep the state so you can detect transitions.

```
let websiteState = false;
let task = cron.schedule("* * * * * *", async() => {
  let isWebsite = await checkGameStatus();
  if (websiteState != isWebsite) {
    if (isWebsite) {
      console.log("In website")
    } else {
      console.log("In game")
    }
    websiteState = isWebsite;
  }
});
```